# Disadvantages/limitations with local storage for a diary app

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a diary app with entries stored in local storage. I wondered what the limitations/disadvantages might be when it comes to the local storage of these written and image entries- any ideas would be helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple.

- Local Storage has a modest size limit - around 5 MB. If a user writes a whole lot, or pastes in large amounts of text, they may find themselves running into the limit, breaking the application. Consider using [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB) instead, which is fundamentally similar to Local Storage with regards to what you want, except that it has a much, much larger size limit. To easily interact with IndexedDB, consider using [localForage](https://github.com/localForage/localForage).
- If the data is stored on the client, if the client loses their browser data, their stored text will be lost too. Storing the data on a server too would be more reliable.